# Pass object to two threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have 3 threads. 1 threads collects data and returns it
`var1 = Thread1.start()`

Thread 2 and thread 3 use this variable `var1` to do routine. 
I'm not sure If I do it right. because sometimes `var1` is returned and it's not an empty list, I store it in variable of each thread, use list comprehension to extract data. In debugging logs I see elements that must be in thread 3, but debugging logger of that thread returns nothing.

In Thread 2 and thread 3 algoritm:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self.lock = threading.RLock()

def do_smth2(self,var1):
   self.lock.acquire()
      var1_2 = var1
   self.lock.release()

def do_smth3(self,var3)
   self.lock.acquire()
     var1_3 = var1
   self.lock.release()
```

in `main`

```py
   object = thread1.start()
   thread2.start(object)
   thread3.start(object)
```

Thread 2 and thread 3 run in the same time, and I use `time.sleep(3)` if `var1_3` or `var1_2` is `None` (this is a `list` type) or when `len(var1_3) <0`

**EDIT**

```py
class Application:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = RootLogger()
        self.logger.set_config(__name__, sys_log)
        self.adapter = Adapter()
        self.transit_listener = TransitListener()

    def run(self):

        #start listeners
        transits_list = self.transit_listener.start()        
        self.adapter.start(transits_list)


        # start REST service
        RestWebService().run()
```

Thread 1

```py
class TransitListener:
    def __init__(self):
         self.interval = session_interval

    def _transits_data(self):
        # while polling is running change interval after 1st cycle
        while datetime.now() >= session_interval:
            result = self.connector.query(self.statement,
                                          fetch=True)
            self.logger.debug(result)
            # store result
            self.transits_queue.put(result)
            self.logger.debug(self.interval)
            time.sleep(5)
            # change interval
            self._interval_granularity()
            self.logger.debug(self.interval)

     def start(self):
        self.worker = Thread(target=self._transits_data)
        self._configure()
        self.logger.info("Starting thread 'transists listener'...")
        try:
            self.worker.start()
            if self.worker.is_alive():
                self.logger.info("Thread 'transits listener' started")
                # return result from queue
                return self.transits_queue.get()
```

Thread 2 and 3

```py
class Adapter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = RootLogger()
        self.logger.set_config(name=__name__, logfile=epp_log)
        self.lock = RLock()
        self.threads = []


    def _session_start(self, transits):
        while datetime.now() >= session_interval:
            self.lock.acquire()
            transit_list = transits
            self.lock.release()
            self.logger.debug(f"ENTRIES {transit_list}")

    def _session_stop(self, transits):
        while datetime.now() >= session_interval:
            self.lock.acquire()
            transit_list = transits
            self.lock.release()
            self.logger.debug(f"EXITS{transit_list}")
  def start(self, transits):
        # prepare SQL tables
        # define priority of threads

        # 1st
        session_start_thread = Thread(target=self._session_start, args=(transits,))
        self.threads.append(session_start_thread)

        # 2nd
        session_stop_thread = Thread(target=self._session_stop, args=(transits,))
        self.threads.append(session_stop_thread)
        self.threads[0].start()
        self.threads[1].start()
```

Comment: could you not use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) for this?

Comment: Thread1 returns object from algoritm with `queue` method: `q.put(result)`, in thread `return q.get()`. `Res` is a list, so thread1 returns a list and clears queue. In two other threads I'm trying to use the same object - list, because `q.get()` flushes `queue`. I've added some code  from main method.

Comment: Can you add the surrounding class in the question as well, apart from what you already added in the question?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh added.